# How to show all merges data without return #VALUE?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've 2 tabs, it names `Group A` and `Group B`, like this :

[image]
[image]

We can see no data rows in the `Group B`. When I've been trying to merge this, I've an error like this :

[image]

I've been trying to add `IFERROR` but it doesn't work,
So, how to fix this? Thanks in advance

For the link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xmUMlprKNh1r6O81KuLtaNOQchx5sYn_ihirkG9tzWk/edit#gid=128715108

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were me, I would do it this way:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(QUERY({SPLIT(IFERROR('Group A'!A1&"|"&FILTER('Group A'!A3:A&"|"&'Group A'!B3:B&"|"&'Group A'!D3:D,'Group A'!B3:B<>""),"|||"),"|",1,0); SPLIT(IFERROR('Group B'!A1&"|"&FILTER('Group B'!A3:A&"|"&'Group B'!B3:B&"|"&'Group B'!D3:D,'Group B'!B3:B<>""),"|||"),"|",1,0) },"Select * Where Col1 Is Not Null")))`

The core of this is just two stacked arrays. In each:

The group name (from 'Group A'!A1 or 'Group B'!A1 respectively) and the target columns' data is concatenated with the pipe symbol ("|"). If there is no matching data, the IFERROR assigns three pipes "|||") as the value. This way, when each array is SPLIT, there will always be something to SPLIT, even if there was no data (the IFERROR value of three pipes will just split to four null cells).

Notice that the two final parameters of each SPLIT are 1,0 (i.e., which together mean "split by each symbol and keep blank results").

The `QUERY` wrap isn't strictly necessary, but it just assures that no stray rows of blanks get appended to the final array.

And the outermost IFERROR wrap accounts for the case where no data is retrieved from *either* sheet (since QUERY of two rows of nulls with "Where Col1 Is Not Null" would be an error).

Comment: Note a slight change to my formula (copy and paste to your sheet again). And if this does what you expected, please mark my reply post as "Best Answer" so that other contributors can see at a glance from the issues page that this has been resolved to satisfaction. Thanks.

Comment: Yes Sir, thank you, by the way I still have one question, when I changed `Salary` with `hireDate` (Date Formatted) and in the result is the date changed to integer. So how to make it still in date format?

Comment: The integer is the raw form of dates in Google Sheets, representing the number of days that have passed since December 31, 1899. Just click on the "D" at the top of Column D to select the whole column, then choose Format > Number from the menu and choose a date format you like. OR... go to the 'Group A' sheet, click on a cell that contains a date, click the format paintbrush in the menu, go to the 'Result' sheet, and then click on the "D" at the top of Column D; this will apply that date format to the entire column.

Comment: I see you still have a previous version of the formula in your sheet. Please copy and paste the formula as it now shows in my post, since it will take care of one rare case for you. Thank you for marking the post as "Best Answer."

Comment: Ah I see, thank you and finally I'm using your solution into my real project.